# Stored procedure where I'm able to add values and take a datediff

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm new to stored procedures and I am looking for a way to do some calculations within the stored procedure. I previously would pull the data into my app and write the formulas there.

Let's say I have a data that looks like this:

```
ID        Name              Dob           Number      Number2
-------------------------------------------------------------
17        Bob smith         1/1/1980      20          17


Select ID, Name, Dob, Number, Number2 
from tblA 
where Dob > '01/01/1950'
```

What I'm hoping to do is do some calculation but I'm not really sure how to go about it, basically what I'd like to do is have these additional fields pulled from this stored procedure:

```
NumberTotal        DaysfromToday
---------------------------------
37                 Today - Dob
```

Is something like this possible?

Desired end result:

```
ID    Name         Dob       Number      Number2   NumberTotal      DaysFT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
17    Bob smith    1/1/1980  20          17        37               Today-Dob
```

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server,` etc..) that you are using.

Comment: PSA: [ISO date format](https://xkcd.com/1179/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

```
Select ID, Number + Number2 as NumberTotal, DateDiff(DAY, Dob, GetDate()) as DaysFromToday
from tblA 
where Dob > '01/01/1950'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datediff()` function :

```
select *, (Number + Number2) as NumberTotal, datediff(day, dob, getdate()) as DaysfromToday
from tblA 
where Dob > '01/01/1950'
```

Comment: I want to see Number and Number2 in their seperate fields, same with DOB, so basically the Sum and DateDiff I just want in additional columns